# Assigning attribute values to map of city based on location picked?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, points-to-line

I have a city map in arc GIS, with each parcel having it's own parcel number as an attribute in addition to other attributes.

I need to create a second layer of the same map and add data to it based on 4 additional attributes. These attributes are based on location in the city (the city would be split into 4 sections, each section would need to be it's own attribute.)

I tried to create a new feature class with the map, then I tried to split it up into 4 sections but then I get stuck on how to create the attributes and assign it to those areas with the parcel numbers.

Anyone have an idea on how I can digitize a map and assign it attributes? All the while linking it to my basemap that has parcel numbers for the addresses and attributes?

Comment: It appears that you have not yet taken the [Tour] to learn how our focussed Q&A format differs from discussion forums and other Q&A sites.  As it stands I think your question is too broad because it says "here is roughly what I need to do, can you tell me how to do it?" We are good with "here is roughly what I need to do", but it needs to be followed by "this is precisely what I have tried and where I am stuck".  By precisely I mean the actual steps with tool/function names.

Answer (score 1):

If by map, you mean a feature class, what I think you need to do is:

1. Right-click on the feature class (your city map) and export it as a new feature
2. Start editing the newly copied feature [ by going to the feature editor set], and select the specific features you want to edit and update them in the table. (the selected feature becomes highlighted in the attributed table). This is of course assuming the feature (map?) is already sectioned geometrically. If not use the split polygons tool to split your polygon into the 4 sections (assuming the map just is one polygon that covers the whole city).

Note: it will be much easier if you post some illustrations of both the geographic and the table side of your data, as the question right now is a bit confusing.

Comment: So I saw your post [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164074/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-a-separate-map-layer-with-attributes). In that case, What you need to do is digitize your scanned city map after geo-referencing it, you only need to geo-reference it if you want to be geographically accurate. If you just need a graphics (for website or brochure, no analysis), you can straight go to digitizing. 1. Create an empty feature in arc catalog (polygon probably) 2.bring it in Arcmap, start editing and start drawing your boundary lines by tracing the map underneath.